# How to render a view in EmberJS 1.13.8 without refreshing the page?

Tags: ember.js

Sorry if this question is too naive,but I am getting confused a lot on rendering views in Ember.

I have a 'Person' route. I am able to do CRUD operations on it.

router.js

```
  this.route('person', function() {
    this.route('index', { path: '' });
 });
```

controllers/person/index.js

```
actions: {    
  createPerson: function() {
  var person = this.get('store').createRecord('person');
  this.set('person', person);
  this.set('editPersonPane', true);
},

editPerson: function(person) {
  this.set('person', person);
  this.set('editPersonPane', true);
},

closeEditPerson: function() {
 this.get('person').rollback();
 this.set('editPersonPane', false);
},

savePerson: function(person) {
  var _this = this;
  person.save().then(function() {
    _this.set('editPersonPane', false);
    Ember.get(_this, 'flashMessages').success('person.flash.personUpdateSuccessful');
  }, function() {
    Ember.get(_this, 'flashMessages').danger('apiFailure');
  });
},

deletePerson: function(person) {
  var _this = this;
  person.destroyRecord().then(function() {
    _this.set('editPersonPane', false);
    Ember.get(_this, 'flashMessages').success('person.flash.personDeleteSuccessful');
  }, function() {
    Ember.get(_this, 'flashMessages').danger('apiFailure');
  });
}
}
```

What I want to do now is when I want to create a new person, a form slides in to create it. After filling up the form, I want the list view of persons to be updated immediately, without refreshing the page. Right now, I have been able to add the form and when I add a new person, I get a successful flash message but it's not updated in the view immediately. I have to refresh the page.

It might have to do something with observers but I am still not sure how.

Comment: `person.save().then(function(savedPerson) { savedPerson.reload(); // rest of your code});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reloading a saved object will allow you to avoid having to refresh the page:

```
savePerson: function(person) {
  var _this = this;
  person.save().then(function(saved) {
     saved.reload();
    _this.set('editPersonPane', false);
    Ember.get(_this, 'flashMessages').success('person.flash.personUpdateSuccessful');
  }, function() {
    Ember.get(_this, 'flashMessages').danger('apiFailure');
  });
}
```

Also, it's worth noting that if you destructure and use [ES6](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) syntax, you can clean up your code a bit as follows:

```
//controllers/person/index.js
//at the top of the file
import Ember from 'ember';

const { get, set } = Ember;

//other code

  actions: {    

  //other actions

    savePerson(person): {
      person.save().then((saved) => {
        saved.reload();
        set(this, 'editPersonPane', false);
        get(this, 'flashMessages').success('person.flash.personUpdateSuccessful');
      }, () {
        get(this, 'flashMessages').danger('apiFailure');
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ohh my fault. This would work in normal cases, but in scenario, I have pagination enabled in the model. I have created a new question for that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33779235/how-to-update-the-ui-immediately-when-a-new-record-is-added-related-to-ember-cl

Answer (score 0):

Which route is displaying your persons list?

Wouldn't something like this work better, so you can display the list and then edit a person within the persons.hbs outlet?

```
this.route('persons', function() {
    this.route('person', { path: 'id' });
});
```